# How can I get the name of the account the application pool runs under inside of my WCF method?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-4.0, application-pool

## ***BACKGROUND***

---

I have created a Silverlight / WCF based deployment tool that will be hosted in 2 places:  the first will touch the development, testing, and staging servers, and the second will touch the production servers.

Inside the tool, it needs to know where it is so that it can show the appropriate environments and their servers for configuration.

The easiest way to do that is to pull the name of the account the WCF service is running under and based on that return the appropriate DeploymentMode value.

## ***PROBLEM***

---

My problem is that I can't get the name of the account the application pool is running under from within my WCF method.  All I seem to pull from `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is my own windows logon.

The application pools for both, the tool and the service, are running under a specific domain account, which is not mine.

## ***QUESTION***

---

How can I get the name of the account the application pool runs under inside of my WCF method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Environment.UserName` in conjunction with `Environment.UserDomainName` to build the **AppPool Identity Name**.

Comment: Wow, fast response and dead on (minus my _small_ correction). I have no idea why I didn't try `Environment`, but it just never dawned on me.  Thanks!